# pycord says "TypeError: object TextChannel can't be used in 'await' expression"

Tags: python, pycord

I use Pycord, and when I use `channel = bot.get_channel(975050208264200242)` with `await channel.send(embed = embed2)` to send message it says me `TypeError: object TextChannel can't be used in 'await' expression`

What can I do?

I also tried using it without await and I got this: `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

By the way I'm new to python and Pycord

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can delete the line `await channel.send(embed = embed2)` to avoid the error.

Comment: Yes, but I need to make my bot send message to that channel

Comment: Could you send the portion of the code? That would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to provide more code, but from what I understand you can only await asynchronous functions (ones defined by async def). Example:

```py
@bot.command
async def command(ctx):
```

If this doesn’t help, please edit your question and add the whole command.